# Why that thing every time skip next element?

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions

Hello I want to output every positive element that is even. I use VA_LIST. The compiler counts numbers only from 1 to 4, 4 to 8 is not counted, what is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int MyPerfectF(int num, ...) {
    int sum = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);
    int x;
    while (va_arg(args, int) != NULL) {
        x = va_arg(args, int);
        if (x > 0 && x % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%d ", x);
            sum++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nAmount of true numbers is: %d", sum);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int num = 5;
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf_s("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    MyPerfectF(num, a, b, c, d, NULL);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `va_arg` twice each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [va_arg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg) *[emphasis mine]*:

> T va_arg( va_list ap, T );

> The va_arg macro expands to an expression of **type T** that corresponds to the **next parameter** from the va_list ap.

In `MyPerfectF()` function,

```
    while (va_arg(args, int) != NULL) {
        x = va_arg(args, int);
```

`va_arg` is called twice, so if the input contains even number at even place then all those even number will be counted otherwise they are not.

Apart from this there is one more problem in your code -
In context of your program, **type T** is `int`. Compiler must be throwing a warning on comparison statement `(va_arg(args, int) != NULL)` of `while` loop condition.

You don't need to pass `NULL` to indicate the termination of arguments. Instead, pass the value of `num` as number of variable arguments passed to `MyPerfectF()` function, like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int num = 4;
    .....
    .....
    MyPerfectF(num, a, b, c, d);
}
```

and in `MyPerfectF()` replace the `while` loop with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
```

Also, you can assign the return value of `scanf()` to `num` and pass it to `MyPerfectF()` function, this will ensure that the `MyPerfectF()` function will read only those arguments which are successfully read and assigned by `scanf()`. Putting these altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int MyPerfectF(int num, ...) {
    int sum = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        int x = va_arg(args, int);
        if (x > 0 && x % 2 == 0) {
            printf("%d ", x);
            sum++;
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
    printf("\nAmount of true numbers is: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf ("Enter 4 values:\n");
    int num = scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    MyPerfectF(num, a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```